# How to avoid deadlock in printing alphanumeric numbers concurrently

Tags: go, concurrency, deadlock, goroutine

I'm new to golang and I just wish to print out 10 alphanumeric numbers combining elements from numeber-range and character-range.

I decided to do it concurrently, but I've been running into an error regarding deadlock.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type alphanumeric struct {
    anAlphabet string
    aNumber    string
}

func (someStruct alphanumeric) pairAlphanumeric() string {

    return someStruct.aNumber + someStruct.anAlphabet

}

func main() {

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    numbers := []string{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"}
    alphabets := []string{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"}

    //var aleph alphanumeric
    //var alephS []alphanumeric

    wg.Add(len(alphabets))
    go func(numbers []string, alphabets []string) {
        defer wg.Done()
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            makeAleph(numbers, alphabets)
        }
    }(numbers, alphabets)

    wg.Wait()
} // end of main()

func makeAleph(numbers []string, alphabets []string) {

    var aleph alphanumeric

    aleph.anAlphabet = aNum(numbers)
    aleph.aNumber = anAlph(alphabets)

    fmt.Println(aleph.pairAlphanumeric())

    //return aleph.pairAlphanumeric()
}

func randomIndex() int {
    randTime := time.Time.UnixNano(time.Now())

    rand.Seed(randTime)

    return rand.Intn(10)
}

func aNum(numbers []string) string {

    return numbers[randomIndex()]

}

func anAlph(alphabets []string) string {

    return alphabets[randomIndex()]

}
```

And the error that it throws after printing the required numbers correctly is:

```
❯ go run aleph.go
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [semacquire]:
sync.runtime_Semacquire(0xc42000e2dc)
    /Users/eklavya/.gvm/gos/go1.8/src/runtime/sema.go:47 +0x34
sync.(*WaitGroup).Wait(0xc42000e2d0)
    /Users/eklavya/.gvm/gos/go1.8/src/sync/waitgroup.go:131 +0x7a
main.main()
    /Users/eklavya/Projects/Polyglot/TedTalks/goTED/experiments/async/aleph.go:38 +0x14c

goroutine 5 [chan receive (nil chan)]:
main.makeAleph(0xc420084000, 0xa, 0xa, 0xc420001520, 0x1a, 0x1a)
    /Users/eklavya/Projects/Polyglot/TedTalks/goTED/experiments/async/aleph.go:61 +0x134
main.main.func1(0xc42000e2d0, 0xc420084000, 0xa, 0xa, 0xc420001520, 0x1a, 0x1a)
    /Users/eklavya/Projects/Polyglot/TedTalks/goTED/experiments/async/aleph.go:35 +0x94
created by main.main
    /Users/eklavya/Projects/Polyglot/TedTalks/goTED/experiments/async/aleph.go:37 +0x13e

goroutine 6 [chan send (nil chan)]:
main.aNum(0x0, 0xc420084000, 0xa, 0xa)
    /Users/eklavya/Projects/Polyglot/TedTalks/goTED/experiments/async/aleph.go:79 +0x5b
main.makeAleph.func1(0xc42000e2e0, 0x0, 0xc420084000, 0xa, 0xa)
    /Users/eklavya/Projects/Polyglot/TedTalks/goTED/experiments/async/aleph.go:51 +0x73
created by main.makeAleph
    /Users/eklavya/Projects/Polyglot/TedTalks/goTED/experiments/async/aleph.go:52 +0xad

goroutine 7 [chan send (nil chan)]:
main.anAlph(0x0, 0xc420001520, 0x1a, 0x1a)
    /Users/eklavya/Projects/Polyglot/TedTalks/goTED/experiments/async/aleph.go:85 +0x5b
main.makeAleph.func2(0xc42000e2e0, 0x0, 0xc420001520, 0x1a, 0x1a)
    /Users/eklavya/Projects/Polyglot/TedTalks/goTED/experiments/async/aleph.go:56 +0x73
created by main.makeAleph
    /Users/eklavya/Projects/Polyglot/TedTalks/goTED/experiments/async/aleph.go:57 +0xff
exit status 2
```

How can I avoid deadlock in printing alphanumeric numbers concurrently?

Comment: Just as a side note, you should definitely not be calling `rand.Seed` for every random number generated.

Comment: @hobbs, so apart from violating DRY, does it have a major effect on performance?

Comment: Not on performance, only on correctness. It makes your random numbers much less random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code is not concurrent at all. All the alphanumeric codes are generated sequentially in a single `for` loop running in the sole goroutine you are creating besides `main`.

You are adding `len(alphabets) == 26` to `wg.Wait`. That means you need to call 26 `wg.Done` for the call to `wg.Wait` to complete. Each `wg.Done` call reduces the waitgroup counter by one.

In your code, you are calling `wg.Done` only once. That means waitgroup counter stays at 25 once your goroutine returns and the call to `wg.Wait` would never return since no other goroutine is running that may reduce the waitgroup counter by making further calls to `wg.Done`.

To (vaguely) get what you want, you can try something like this:

```
// ...

n := 10 // number of codes you want to print

wg.Add(n)

for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
  go func(numbers []string, alphabets []string) {
    defer wg.Done()
    makeAleph(numbers, alphabets)
  }(numbers, alphabets)

wg.Wait()

// ...
```

Now, `n` goroutines will be spawned, each responsible for printing one code by calling `makeAleph`. As soon as a goroutine returns, `wg.Done` is called. A total `n` `wg.Done`s are called allowing call to `wg.Wait` in `main` to complete.